# What exactly is deinit doing here? And why?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, deinit

My Question has to do with the sample code provided for Firebase. You can find it on [Github](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/blob/master/ios-starter/swift-starter/FriendlyChatSwift/FCViewController.swift) or in the [Documentation](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/#0). Anyway, I don't really understand what the "deinit" on the database reference is doing. I read the deinit swift documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Deinitialization.html). I think I understand the purpose of using a deinit, but I'm not sure how it works in this case.

```
let kBannerAdUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"

@objc(FCViewController)
class FCViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,
    UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,
        InviteDelegate {

  // Instance variables
  @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var sendButton: UIButton!
  var ref: DatabaseReference!
  var messages: [DataSnapshot]! = []
  let posts = [Post]()

  var msglength: NSNumber = 10
  fileprivate var _refHandle: DatabaseHandle!

  var storageRef: StorageReference!
  var remoteConfig: RemoteConfig!

  @IBOutlet weak var banner: GADBannerView!
  @IBOutlet weak var clientTable: UITableView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.clientTable.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "tableViewCell")

    configureDatabase()
    configureStorage()
    configureRemoteConfig()
    fetchConfig()
    loadAd()
    logViewLoaded()
  }

    deinit {

        // NOT REALLY SURE WHAT THIS DOES
        if let refHandle = _refHandle {
            self.ref.child("messages").removeObserver(withHandle: _refHandle)
        }
    }

func configureDatabase() {
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    // Listen for new messages in the Firebase database
    _refHandle = self.ref.child("messages").observe(.childAdded, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) -> Void in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

        // EACH SNAPSHOT IS PLACED IN THE MESSAGES ARRAY
        strongSelf.messages.append(snapshot)

        // MAKE THE NUMBER OF ROWS IN THE FEED == THE NUMBER OF SNAPSHOTS
        strongSelf.clientTable.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: strongSelf.messages.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During initialization, your view controller adds a `childAdded` observer to a given Firebase database node. The passed in closure would still be called *even* after the view controller was long gone (i.e., deallocated). Firebase keeps a *strong* reference to it (and a *weak* reference to your view controller, by the way). This unnecessary calling might not be a major issue (yet!), but it's wrong nevertheless.

The `deinit` code prevents that from happening.

The *deinitializer* is called immediately before your view controller is deallocated. As such, it provides a nice place to *remove* that observer from the aforementioned database node. The observer (reference) is stored in the `_refHandle` property.

By the way, you could simplify your observer removing code to:

```
if let refHandle = _refHandle {
    self.ref.removeObserver(withHandle: _refHandle)
}
```

you don't need to call `removeObserver` on the *same* node it was registered on.

---

**Weak View Controller**. The `[weak self]` qualifier, in the aforementioned closure, is what specifies that Firebase should keep only a weak reference to your view controller. This is crucial to ensure that the view controller is properly released from memory when no longer needed. Without it, your `deinit` would never be called!